# Use Non default database with ManyRelatedManager methods in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager, manyrelatedmanager

I want to use a non default database with ManyRelatedManager's set method in django.

I have tried the following methods:

1. By mentioning the `using` method in the query

   It gives me the following error:
   `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'set'`
2. By using the db_manager with the relatedmanager like this: `modelA.modelB_set.db_manager('new_db').set(modelB_list)`

   This doesn't give any error, but it uses the default database to do this.

Is there any way that I can use a non default database with set method of ManyRelatedManager? Thanks in advance.